# Html ,CSS Fixed width highlight hover background

Tags: html, css

Im trying to achieve full width hover background on list items.

[image]

I need to get the gray background full width towards the left also.

How do i achieve this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 additonal-resources-cont">
                <h3 class="header-additnl-resources">Additional Resources </h3>
                <ul class="additional-resrc-ul nopadding">
                    <li><a href="" class="additional-resources-href">Login / Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="additional-resources-href">Request Samples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="additional-resources-href">Technical Documentation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.additional-resources-href:hover {
    background: #1daeeb;
    opacity: 4.5;
    background-color: #BFCDD5 !important;
}


.additional-resources-href {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.additional-resrc-ul li:before {
    content: "• ";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1DAEEB;
}

.additional-resrc-ul li:hover {
    background: #1daeeb;
    opacity: 4.5;
    background-color: #BFCDD5;
}

.additional-resrc-ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 3.5em;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to cover circle bullets also while hovering? If yes, then you cant do so. Because that is not the part of the DOM. Make it by custom design and then style it similar to that. i dont find any issue in your code

Comment: yes i want to cover the left side full covering the bullets also, i mean till the left side gray margin

Comment: Inspect box model - It's padding not width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pseudo element that will overflow outside the li and cover all the width like this :

```css
.additional-resources-href:hover {
  background: #1daeeb;
  opacity: 4.5;
  background-color: #BFCDD5 !important;
}

.additional-resources-href {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.additional-resrc-ul li {
  position:relative;
}
.additional-resrc-ul li:before {
  content: "• ";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1DAEEB;
}

.additional-resrc-ul li:after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -30%;
  right: 0;
}

.additional-resrc-ul li:hover {
  
  opacity: 4.5;
}

.additional-resrc-ul li:hover::after {
  background: #BFCDD5;
}

.additional-resrc-ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 3.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 additonal-resources-cont">
  <h3 class="header-additnl-resources">Additional Resources </h3>
  <ul class="additional-resrc-ul nopadding">
    <li><a href="" class="additional-resources-href">Login / Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="additional-resources-href">Request Samples</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="additional-resources-href">Technical Documentation</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am able to get to the right side width, but i need to get to the left margin full as shown in my updated image

Comment: @Sach it's not like i did ? it's full width no ? the left margin is covered

Comment: i changed as per ur code, i still dont get the full width for the left margin!

Comment: @Sach don't forget to add `position:relative` to the li ... also is it working fine in the snippet here ?

Comment: Yes relative position is there, i wonder how its working in snippet here...when i hover after the li after, i can see the left side widht , but its not showing on actual hover.

Comment: @Sach maybe you have other CSS conflict

Comment: Ok letme check, i will accept answer as of now..thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Here I create the menu with flex column and apply hover to each item and added a transition.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

.resources-list{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.resources-item{
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

.resources-item:hover{
  background-color: gray;
}

.resources-item:before{
  content: '• ';
}

.app-content{
  flex: 0 0 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="resources-list">
            <h3>Resources List</h3>
            <div class="resources-item">lorem3</div>
            <div class="resources-item">lorem3</div>
            <div class="resources-item">lorem3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="app-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum mollitia illum voluptates. Cumque earum cupiditate explicabo dolorum, praesentium dolor quia consequatur incidunt iste excepturi blanditiis dolores quibusdam odio quas quo.
        </div
    </div>
```